# ChatGPT Integration with Java gives 429 Too Many Requests

Tags: chatgpt-api

`org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$TooManyRequests: 429 Too Many Requests: "{<EOL>    "error": {<EOL>        "message": "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.",<EOL>        "type": "insufficient_quota",<EOL>        "param": null,<EOL>        "code": null<EOL>    }<EOL>}<EOL>"`

Hi I am getting 429 Too Many Requests error even though i have tried it first time .

Could you please help me to assist solution for this

Complete error stack-trace

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$TooManyRequests: 429 Too Many Requests: "{    "error": {        "message": "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.",        "type": "insufficient_quota",        "param": null,        "code": null    }}"

Comment: Do you have a paid pricing scheme attached to your account or is it the free tier?